# how to display a background-image under another background-image in CSS

Tags: html, image, css

i'm trying to figure out how to display another background image under my first image. I'm pretty noob to HTML & css and I'm trying to figure out some things but can't seem to find this. I know the picture is there because when I add a `<p>` between the section of the second background image, you can see a small piece of the picture (which is probably the height of the `<p>`-tag.). So I guess there's something wrong with my width & height. However, I've tried to fill in the exact height & width but this resulted in a very zoomed in picture. Maybe this has something to do with using the REM wrong? I have no idea, I guess this isn't so hard to do but I'm still failing to succeed. This is what I have so far. You won't see the pictures because they're local, I hope this doesn't matter? Thanks a lot for the help!

Edit: just to be clear, there are 2 full-screen images (main.jpg & kampvuur.jpg that needs to be displayed full screen, the other images are on top of the fullscreen background-images and are just used for design)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWGZR.jpg

```css
html{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
}

*, *:before, *:after{
  box-sizing: inherit;
 margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  height: 100%;
}

.bg{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

.mainpage{
    background-image: url(../assets/img/main.jpg);
}

.mainpage-text{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 20rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.title{
  background-image: url(../assets/img/tentacion-small.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 53.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.titlespan{
  visibility: hidden;
}

q{
  background-image: url(../assets/img/quote-sm.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 63rem;
  height: 3.1rem;
}

.gif{
  background-image: url(../assets/img/arrowdown.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

.stars{
  background-image: url(../assets/img/kampvuur.jpg);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>


    <header class="bg mainpage">
      <section class="mainpage-text">
        <h1 class="title"><span class="titlespan">tentacion</span></h1>
        <q><span class="titlespan">quote</span></q>
        <div class="gif"></div>
      </section>
    </header>

    <main>
      <section class="bg stars">
      <p>test</p>
      </section>

    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Both images are there --> https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/4a674n5v/2/ Could you provide an image of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If these are just for design purposes and don't need an interaction you can look up multiple backgrounds image within 1 element (such as the body tag) http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ -- Also you can use https://placehold.it/200x200 to replace your local images so it's visible what you wan't to do.

Comment: @ovokuro https://imgur.com/a/5jeVh here's a link, I made this one in photoshop, every background-image should be +- a full page

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove padding-bottom from .message-text and change this css

```
.title{
  background-image: url('https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 92px;
  width: 272px;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

```css
html{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
}

*, *:before, *:after{
  box-sizing: inherit;
 margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  height: 100%;
}

.bg{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

.mainpage{
    background-image: url('http://anatomyzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/skin3.general-boxed-bg-image.jpg');
}

.mainpage-text{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 0rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.title{
  background-image: url('https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 92px;
  width: 272px;
  margin-bottom:0;
}

.titlespan{
  visibility: hidden;
}

q{
  background-image: url(../assets/img/quote-sm.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 63rem;
  height: 3.1rem;
}

.gif{
  background-image: url(../assets/img/arrowdown.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

.stars{
  background-image: url(../assets/img/kampvuur.jpg);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>


    <header class="bg mainpage">
      <section class="mainpage-text">
        <h1 class="title"><span class="titlespan">tentacion</span></h1>
        <q><span class="titlespan">quote</span></q>
        <div class="gif"></div>
      </section>
    </header>

    <main>
      <section class="bg stars">
      <p>test</p>
      </section>

    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I thinks it's not really clear where I'm trying to go. I have made something in photoshop real quick. https://imgur.com/a/5jeVh